# Using the label prop for FormControlLabel

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, radio-button, accordion

I am trying to nest a **RadioGroup** inside **AccordionDetails**, then insert the **Accordion** list as options inside an **Autocomplete** component within its renderOption props.

The problem I am having is that clicking on the label (which is a span element when inspected) of the radio button closes the Autocomplete dropdown list without saving the selected value to state.

Thanks in advance!

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-brun8?file=/demo.js

Comment: That is exactly what I was expecting, and definitely not a solution I even imagined. Thank you so much! You have no idea how much time you saved me.

Comment: I am putting this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `e.preventDefault()` on click of the label panel

```
const getLabel = ({ label, value }) => (
    <div
      value={value}
      onClick={(e) => {
        setValue(e.target.getAttribute("value"));
        e.preventDefault();
      }}
    >
      {label}
    </div>
  );
```

Form Control Label:-

```
<FormControlLabel
              value="other"
              control={<Radio />}
              label={getLabel({ label: "Others", value: "other" })}
            />
```

Codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-e3hom?file=/demo.js:2650-2836